# Ошибка "Недопустимое имя строки" при работе приложения C# с подключением MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Начал делать приложение на WinForm C# и сейчас разбираюсь, как работать с базой данных. В коде кнопки входа при авторизации идет запрос в базу на проверку наличия данной связки логина и пароля. Сейчас в базе есть только admin/admin, и когда в запущенном приложении вводишь данные логин/пароль, выдается ошибка от базы "Недопустимое имя столбца "admin"". Подскажите, как решается данная проблема.

Таблица, к которой идет select, состоит лишь из логина и пароля.

В коде пока реализована функция входа только для Работников.

```
string login = textBox1.Text;
string pass = textBox2.Text;
string tablename="none";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable table = new DataTable();

if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Работник")
{
    tablename = "AuthClient";
}else if(comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Работодатель")
{
    tablename = "AuthCompany";
    //"select * from {tablename} where logUs = {login} and passUS = {pass}"
    //  "select * from [dbo].[{tablename}] where  [logUs] = {login} and [passUs] = {pass}" */
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Выберите тип пользователя");
}
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"select * from [dbo].[{tablename}] where  [logUs] = {login} and [passUs] = {pass}", huntheader.getConnection());

adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
adapter.Fill(table);

if(table.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    label4.Text = "Success";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

используйте всегда параметры:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"select * from [dbo].[{tablename}] where  [logUs]=@login and [passUs]=@pass", huntheader.getConnection());

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
```